# Can I have the Man-Class of a jar which exists in a different jar in classpath

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, manifest.mf

I have a scenario where I need to make a dummy executable jar with `Main-Class` from a different jar which is in classpath ( i.e., main class is not in the dummy jar). Is that possible to achieve this?

This is because the jar which is having the main class is not an executable jar but same time I don't want to tamper with it since it is a third-party jar, while as per our standard application invoke scripts we should use an executable jar to invoke the application. Hence I created that dummy jar with `Main-Class` in it. But still it's giving:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

eg : `dummy.jar manifest entries`:

```
Main-Class: com.thirdparty.jar.MainClass
Class-Path:thirdpartyapp.jar
```

Here the `com.thirdparty.jar.MainClass` is inside `thirdpartyapp.jar`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are both jars in the same directory?

Comment: Have you  consider putting a `main` class in your `dummy` jar that just executes the `com.thirdparty.jar.MainClass` of the third party jar...basically a proxy launcher...?

Comment: @erickson Yes both are in same folder.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thats probably next option, but then I'm not sure how the thirdparty application is exiting from it's main class as i don't have the visibility to it.

Comment: Well, the main class does not have to be in the dummy jar. I just tested it out. This should work fine, and I suspect a typo.

Comment: Did you create the dummy jar with `jar`, or some `zip` tool? Because `jar` will do a tiny bit of validation on the manifest, which could help.

Comment: @erickson I did use ant jar task to create this jar with manifest attributes in it. So that shouldn't be a problem. So when you tested did you put the second jar in manifest classpath or you used the java -classpath second.jar? . Anayway let me check again , Thanks for the help

Comment: You can't use `-jar` and `-classpath` together; I used only `-jar dummy.jar`. And `dummy.jar` contains only a MANIFEST.MF with `Main-Class` and `Class-Path` (and version and created-by) attributes. It's just as you describe above, but it works.

Comment: Thanks @erickson I got this working, for a moment I thought it won't work with main-class from an another jar. The issue was with the Class-Path attribute I added in MANIFEST.MF . Thanks for the help.